# when using angular nested form, the first inner form can not be referred in scope

Tags: forms, angularjs, angularjs-scope

When form is nested, the first inner form can not be referred in the controller scope.

I have created a minimal test to reproduce this issue at [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ukEj0J)

#### angular version: 1.2.16

#### Browser:  Chrome, Safari

What's the problem? is there any way to remedy?

Comment: I don;t think you can nest the forms the way you have done in plunker. If you really need such a behavior where forms are to be nested, create a directive instead.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a book called Mastering Web Application Development with AngularJs

There's a section called nesting forms and there it says that you have to nest the forms with ng-include. like so:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="password-form">
    <ng-form name="passwordForm">
        <div ng-show="user.password != user.password2">
        Passwords do not match
        </div>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input ng-model="user.password" type="password" required>
        Creating Advanced Forms
        [ 158 ]
        <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <input ng-model="user.password2" type="password" required>
        </ng-form>
</script>
<form name="form1" novalidate>
    <legend>User Form</legend>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input ng-model="user.name" required>
        <ng-include src="'password-form'"></ng-include>
</form>
```

We define our subform in a partial template. In this case it is inline in a script block
but it could be in a separate file also. Next we have our container form, form1,which
includes the subform by using the ngInclude directive.
The subform has its own validity state and related CSS classes. Also, notice
that because the subform

Comment: ...has a name attribute, it appears as a property on the
container form.

Comment: Sorry I think the important fact here is to use ng-form to nest the forms. I missed this:  Unlike standard HTML forms, AngularJS forms can be nested inside each other.
Since form tags inside other form tags are invalid HTML, AngularJS provides the
ngForm directive for nesting forms.

Comment: As I understand, in angularjs, ngForm is just a ["Nestable alias of form directive"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form), so there should NOT be any difference of using ngForm and form tag

Comment: I tried in your plunker with ng-form="name" and it worked for me

Comment: ng-form for both outer and inner forms? I can't make it working, can you send me your plunker?

Comment: I update the plnkr, I hope you can see it. What I did is to include the nested forms all together and reference it as childs of outer scope.

Comment: Was this usefull for you? If it worked please give it a check :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for this issue, just replace outer form tag with ng-form tag then the first inner form is added to the scope. see this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KOcrFl)

Comment: This may cause problems in Internet Explorer. See the mentioning of IE Restrictions on the AngularJS ngForm API page: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm